# How to retrieve multiple objects from Parse for iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I intend to write an iOS app to retrieve objects from Parse. The [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-classes/iOS) shows you how to retrieve a particular object (with certain id). But I want to retrieve objects based on a particular field in the table.

How do I do it?

Comment: You just create a query and add boundaries or limits to the query like whereKey:@"username" isEqual: parse is well know for the documentation. They have everything written out for you from a-z just take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query whereKey:@"playerName" equalTo:@"Dan Stemkoski"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded.
    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
    // Do something with the found objects
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-basic/iOS